# Xdebug halts when performing HTTP request back to server

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm performing a curl back to the local server in one of my unit tests.  If I enable Xdebug, it halts execution on curl_exec.  I'm guessing this is because the child process spawned by the curl is halted by Xdebug waiting for the first process to finish.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you attach xdebug config from php.ini ?

Comment: What PHP-SAPI do you use? I'm using `cli-server` and have the same problem with curl requests. Not every request will hang, but sometimes the behaviour is undefined. If I use Apache or an other webserver everything works as expected. In my unit tests I've no problems.

Comment: Yes, you can't debug 2 parallel requests (actually can, but its complicated). Do you send any arguments for debug session ?

Comment: I'm running unit tests via the command line.  Server running Apache with mod_php.  Debugging via NetBeans.

Xdebug config: 

xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1

xdebug.idekey="vagrant-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
xdebug.var_display_max_children=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1